# Add caption to image in revealjs Quarto

Tags: r, quarto, caption, reveal.js

I would like to add a caption to an image in a `revealjs` slide. I tried using the `alt` option like describe [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html), but this doesn't seem to work. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

This is an example: 

<img src="elephant.png" alt="A drawing of an elephant.">
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see there is no caption. Also using this syntax `![](elephant.png){fig-alt="A drawing of an elephant."}`  doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a caption to an image in revealjs Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the caption in the first pair of squared brackets:

```markdown
---
output: revealjs
---

![Here's an elephant](elephant.png)
```

[image]

The `alt` option is to provide [alt-text](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_alt.asp) to the figure so that people who can't see it still have a description, but it's not directly visible on the page.